# How to get Audio frames from a MP4 file as bytes using python

Tags: python, audio

I am using a python script to extract audio frames from an mp4 file.

I need to get those frames as bytes, write to stream and feed Azure Speech to text API

Here is my code snippet

```
video = VideoFileClip(video_filename)
audio = video.audio
# Set the desired frame size (number of audio frames)
frame_size = 3200 * 2
# Process audio frames
bytearrays = bytearray()
for audio_frame in audio.iter_frames(fps=16000, dtype='int16'):
    audioFrameBytes = audio_frame.tobytes()
    bytearrays.extend(audioFrameBytes)
    if (len(bytearrays) == frame_size):
        byteObject = bytes(bytearrays)
        stream.write(byteObject)
        print("writing bytes to stream.." + str(len(bytearrays)))
        bytearrays = bytearray()

# Release the resources
audio.close()
video.reader.close()
```

With this I get bytes as 'b\x00\x00\x00\x00

I mean, this is not a valid frames data.

Any help would be much appreciated